# Javascript throws undefined

Tags: javascript

So i've been trying to learn to code and have been using codeAcademy as as resource. I'm currently doing a Rock, Paper, Scissors exercise and my code runs fine but my last `console.log(determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice));"` throws an `undefined` into the console. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
const getUserChoice = (userInput) => {
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  if (userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors') {
    return userInput;
  } else {
    console.log('Error!');
  }
}

const getComputerChoice = () => {
  switch (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)) {
    case 0:
      return 'rock';
    case 1:
      return 'paper';
    case 2:
      return 'scissors';
  }
}

const determineWinner = (userChoice, computerChoice) => {
  if (getUserChoice === getComputerChoice) {
    return 'the game was a tie';
  }
}
if (getUserChoice === 'rock') {
  if (getComputerChoice === 'paper') {
    return 'computer won!';
  } else {
    return 'you won!';
  }
}
if (getUserChoice === 'paper') {
  if (getComputerChoice === 'scissors') {
    return 'computer won!';
  } else {
    return 'you won!';
  }
}
if (getUserChoice === 'scissors') {
  if (getComputerChoice === 'rock') {
    return 'computer won!';
  } else {
    return 'you won!';
  }
}
const playGame = () => {
  const userChoice = getUserChoice('rock');
  const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
  console.log(`You threw: ${userChoice}`);
  console.log(`The computer threw: ${computerChoice}`);
  console.log(determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice));
};
playGame();
```

Comment: `determineWinner` function is closed before the rock paper scissor conditionals. Not sure if typo or actual code

Comment: Given the simplicity of this error I assume you are new to programming and not not familiar with tools available for debugging.  Learning to use the debugger in the developer console will be massively helpful in you JavaScript endeavours.  [Here is a tutorial for using the debugger in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/) but all modern browsers have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring a small syntax mistake in the code you posted here, the problem with the non-working code is that in the function `determineWinner`, you've two variables named `userChoice` and `computerChoice`. But, wrongly, you are using `getUserChoice` and `getComputerChoice`.

```js
const getUserChoice = (userInput) => {
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  if (userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors') {
    return userInput;
  } else {
    console.log('Error!');
  }
}

const getComputerChoice = () => {
  switch (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)) {
    case 0:
      return 'rock';
    case 1:
      return 'paper';
    case 2:
      return 'scissors';
  }
}

const determineWinner = (userChoice, computerChoice) => {
  if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
    return 'the game was a tie';
  }

  if (userChoice === 'rock') {
    if (computerChoice === 'paper') {
      return 'computer won!';
    } else {
      return 'you won!';
    }
  }
  if (userChoice === 'paper') {
    if (computerChoice === 'scissors') {
      return 'computer won!';
    } else {
      return 'you won!';
    }
  }
  if (userChoice === 'scissors') {
    if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
      return 'computer won!';
    } else {
      return 'you won!';
    }
  }
}
const playGame = () => {
  const userChoice = getUserChoice('rock');
  const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
  console.log(`You threw: ${userChoice}`);
  console.log(`The computer threw: ${computerChoice}`);
  console.log(determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice));
};

playGame();
```

Comment: Thankyou! I messed around with that before but it still threw me an error. turns out i had closed off the function with an { at the start of the function and hadn't seen it until i ran a comparison tool.